# Or Operator in mat-select

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

How do I Use a `Or` Operator in mat-select, I wish to disable the selection if the values equate to `x or y`

A Direct Implementation of the OR operator. Defaults to the left Option and Ignores the Right Entirely

```
<mat-select [disabled]="x.status == 'Cancel' || 'Forfeited' " >
```

There is no mention in the [documents regarding `or` Usage?](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#form-field-features)